# Items in Navbar doesnot move with minimizing the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using twitter bootstrap navbar and  list items are shown out of navbar when I minimise my browser to some small size and scroll to the end list item. 
This is what looks as below.

**Navbar when browser is maximised:**

> [image]

**Navbar when browser is minimised:**

> [image]

I would like to have the items stick fixed to the navbar even though the browser is minimised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define **min-width** to your `Navbar`. For example write like this:

```
.Navbar{
 min-width:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php

something like this? (the yellow box saying "Wherever you go, I will find you!")

if yes, then change position to fixed for NAVIGATION.

```
position:fixed;
```

(css)